# Why doesn't node.js garbage collect system resources (such as file handles)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

I've been doing a bunch of async file I/O work on node.js and it strikes me that one has to be extremely careful to catch all error paths in order to not accidentally leak file descriptors in error conditions. But, Javascript is a garbage collected language and this is exactly the kind of things that you're not supposed to have to worry about in a garbage collected environment.

If the variable holding the file descriptor goes out of scope or becomes unreachable from your code it seems that the node.js garbage collector should know that and properly clean up the system resource for you. Javascript in a browser does this with DOM objects. If a DOM object has been removed from the DOM and is held in a Javascript variable that then goes out of scope or becomes unreachable, the browser will automatically clean it up for you. You don't have to manually delete it.  So, certainly this level of integration with non-JS resources is possible.

So, I'm wondering why node.js doesn't have this capability as it seems it would be very useful and would make it a much more robust server development environment?

Is this just a case of node.js being fairly early in its development and this might be a logical improvement over time, but for now there are more important things to work on?

Is this a case of node.js staying at arm's length with the V8 engine and thus not getting integrated to the level that would be required to garbage collect system handles?

Is there some conceptual difficulty that makes doing GC of file handles or other system resources like them impractical?

Comment: Does it actually never close the handles, or just does so unreliably (only when and if the corresponding JS object is garbage collected, which can be far later or perhaps, sometimes, never)?

Comment: My understanding is that it never closes the file handles unless you call `fs.close(fd)` or `fs.closeSync(fd)`.  The problem probably stems from the fact that the file descriptors in node.js are just plain old numbers (not objects) so the JS engine just treats them as a number (e.g. nothing to do when garbage collecting other than free the space occupied by the number).  I think the file descriptors would have to be an object that the JS engine knows something about for the JS engine to have a chance at doing something more intelligent with them.

Comment: Which begs the question as to why node.js didn't make file descriptors actually objects so it could do GC with them.

Comment: Note: the new `fs.promises` interface does have [`FileHandle` as an object](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_filehandle) and nodejs "may" close a file automatically, but apparently this is not designed to be a feature that you rely on.

Answer (score 2):

As jfriend00 said, the fact that file descriptors are just numbers in node makes it a problem.  The file descriptor may have been copied, and there's no way to track this.

Further, file descriptors from the master process can be shared with children (see the `cluster` module), which means that even if a process could determine that there are no more references to a particular file descriptor, a different process may have a copy of it.

Its possible that the requirement that file descriptors be shareable in this way is what drove the file descriptor as number decision, since it wouldn't be possible to pass an object with invisible internals between processes.

Comment: Is there even a finalizer concept in JS that, say, streams created by `fs.createWritableStream()` could plug into? If finalizers aren’t a thing in JavaScript, that could be another reason this logic can’t be implemented in pure JavaScript (though I know that V8 has callbacks for when native-backed/sponsored objects get collected).

Comment: @binki No, JS does not have a finalizer concept.  That said, I think the fact that file descriptors get shared with other processes remains the biggest issue; that means you really can't GC file descriptors in any language.

Comment: I don't think that should actually be an issue. If you need to avoid closing a pipe, you can just keep a reference to the descriptor's native wrapper class (if there were one). And if people deem it necessary, that class could have a .detach() to turn off the collection behavior. And you need to define what happens on exec(), except I don't think the JS VM is cleaned up in that case—so GC wouldn't even happen. But moving to something like that *would* be a breaking change.